# creating a trigger - declare variable - Cant get my trigger to work

Tags: mysql, triggers

This trigger is designed to update 'field_csvfilepath_value' to match 'filepath' in the files table (some table details below).  But I cant get it to work, please help.

```sql
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER csv_filpath 
AFTER INSERT ON content_type_importcsv for each row 
begin
    declare p varchar(80)
    set p := (SELECT filepath FROM content_type_importcsv join files where NEW.content_type_importcsv.field_csv1_fid = files.fid)

    set NEW.field_csvfilepath_value = p

    end$$
    delimiter ;
```

This trigger is generating the following error:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set p := (SELECT filepath FROM content_type_importcsv join files where NEW.conte' at line 5

I'm using mysql workbench 5.2

```sql
delimiter $$
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `content_type_importcsv` (
  `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `field_csv1_fid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_csv1_list` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_csv1_data` text,
  `field_csvfilepath_value` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vid`),
  KEY `nid` (`nid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$


CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `fid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `filepath` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `filemime` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `filesize` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`fid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=55 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from multiple syntax errors in your code you can't change column values of a row being inserted in `AFTER` trigger. You should use `BEFORE` event instead.

That being said your trigger can be boiled down to one-statement and therefore doesn't need `BEGIN ... END` block and change of a delimiter.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER csv_fillpath 
BEFORE INSERT ON content_type_importcsv 
FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.field_csvfilepath_value = 
  (
    SELECT filepath 
      FROM files
     WHERE fid = NEW.field_csv1_fid
     LIMIT 1
 );
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61f7a/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors:

1. The one you listed is caused by the `:` in `set p :=`, you should remove it
2. Each line between `begin` and `end$$` should end with `;`
3. You can't update a NEW row in an after trigger, so it should be a before trigger